# Android: sampledata subdirectories not showing up in Android Studio 3.X

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-tools-namespace

I am trying to create UI preview using `tools:text` in my `layout.xml`

For the files inside the `sampledata` directory. I am able to reference them in `xml` and see them in preview But for files inside the `sampledata` **subdirectory** i am not able to access them in `xml` nor i can see the preview as shown in the image below.

What am i doing wrong. Is this even possible ?

[image: Problem Image]

Comment: I also can't see sample .png files that I store in sampledata

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and restarting the Android Studio solved the problem.

After this, just compiling the project shows the latest changes.

I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1

Answer (score 2):

It could happen also that the `sampledata` folder is not inside the same module as it is the layout.

Then, just move the `sampledata` folder to the module that contains the layout.